# Django avatar util problem

Tags: python, django

I've got a django project working on a development server(ubuntu) that we have been working on for a good while. I'm trying to install it now locally on my mac book pro.

I'm relatively new to the Django environment (10 years in LAMP). I tried installing all the relevant packages e.g. south, django-registration etc.

I'm having a problem with django-avatar I think though. When I try run the server I get the following error. I'm not sure where to go from here to fix the problem.  any tips and general education would be greatly appreciated.

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Validating models...
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function inner_run at 0x101d42848>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 48, in inner_run
  self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate
 num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 28, in get_validation_errors
for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 146, in get_app_errors
  self._populate()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 64, in _populate
self.load_app(app_name)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 78, in load_app
models = import_module('.models', app_name)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/Users/derekorgan/Code/python/fishpond/fishpond/../fishpond/fpcasting/models.py", line 3, in <module>
from fishpond.fpprofile.models import ActorProfile
File "/Users/derekorgan/Code/python/fishpond/fishpond/../fishpond/fpprofile/models.py", line 34, in <module>
from avatar.util import invalidate_cache
ImportError: No module named util
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you either have an older (or newer) version of fishpond than django-avatar - fishpond is trying to load up django-avatar's `util` module, but your version of django-avatar doesn't *have* a `util` module. You might want to check and see if there's a certain version of django-avatar that fishpond needs.